# Find an object and its parent by a property value of a nested object with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given the following sample JSON (stringified from the corresponding JavaScript object), I need to extract this information:

1. Find the object in `persons` which has the `reference = 2`.
2. If a person with this `reference` was found, get the `name` of the person's parent element (here: "B").

In the end, I need to build a new object looking similar to this. This won't be problematic but I'm struggling with how to extract these objects from the source. I tried different approaches with `find()`, `map()`, `flatMap()` and `filter()` but none of them really worked.

```js
{
  companyName: "B",
  person: {
    "reference": 2,
    "name": "Bob"
  }
}
```

**Source**

```json
{
  "root": [
    {
      "companies": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "persons": [
            {
              "reference": 1,
              "name": "Alex"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "companies": [
        {
          "name": "B",
          "persons": [
            {
              "reference": 2,
              "name": "Bob"
            },
            {
              "reference": 3,
              "name": "Charles"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in the name of the company you can find it using:

```
const reference = 2;

const company = data.root.flatMap(item => item.companies)
  .find(company => company.persons.some(person => person.reference === reference));

const companyName = company?.name; 

// or if you cannot use optional chaining
const companyName = (company || {}).name;
```

In `data.root.flatMap(item => item.companies)` we iterate through all items in `root`, for each item we select its `companies` property. Since we don't want a nested array we use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten the result by 1 level. This leaves us with an array of companies.

After that we'll call [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the companies array, since we are looking for a specific company name. The criteria of the company is that [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (1 or more) of the `persons` should match the provided `reference`. If no match is found `null` will be returned (from `find()`).

We then take the `find()` result (`company`) and navigate to the name via [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). This will return the `name` of the `company` if present, or `undefined` if `company` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here

```js
let data = JSON.parse(`{
    "root": [
      {
        "companies": [
          {
            "name": "A",
            "persons": [
              {
                "reference": 1,
                "name": "Alex"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "companies": [
          {
            "name": "B",
            "persons": [
              {
                "reference": 2,
                "name": "Bob"
              },
              {
                "reference": 3,
                "name": "Charles"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }`)
  
// GET ALL THE COMPANIES DATA
let companies = data.root.reduce(
    (prevValue, currValue) => {
        prevValue.push(...currValue.companies)
        return prevValue
    },
    []
)

// FIND AND CREATE EXPECTED RESULT SET
let results = companies.reduce(
    (prevValue, currValue) => {
        // loop inside a loop, mind it 
        let refPerson = currValue.persons.find((item)=> item.reference == 2)
        if(refPerson){
            prevValue.push({
             companyName: currValue.name,
             person: refPerson
            })
        }
        return prevValue
    },
    []
)

console.log(results)
```